# How can I get one property from a large JSON object in .net core?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I used the `JsonSerializer` to deserialize JSON before.

And now I have a large JSON to deserialize and I only need one of its properties(Such as `"address":"PK road"`).

I can not order it only replys one property for it is a third-party API.

As we know, I have to code a large model class while using the `JsonSerializer` and most parts of the model are useless.

I don't want to do these useless work on for only get one property.

Is there any other faster way to achieve this? Thank you.

Comment: HAve a look here https://stu.dev/a-look-at-jsondocument/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an alternate solution for System.Text.Json.

You can achieve the same as using [JObject](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm) in newtonsoft

```
var jObj = JObject.Parse(myJsonString);
var myObj = jObj.SelectToken("address").Value<string>());
```